# How to pass a struct and use its field automatically in slog logger?

Tags: go, logging

I'm using slog package. I'm facing the problem that I have to pass too much parameters to it while I have most of these parameters in a struct.

Is there a way to modify the handler to make use of this struct?
Something like what you can do in python, sending a dict or object as extra and then extracting needed parameters from it.

now I have this:

```
g.l.Log(
    context.TODO(),
    slog.LevelInfo,
    "Sending request to server.",
    "Destination", m.route.destination,
    "Protocol", m.route.protocol,
    "Service Identifier", m.route.serID,
    "Session ID", m.GetIdentifier(),
    "Client Connection", client.RemoteAddr().String(),
    "Server Connection", destination.RemoteAddr().String(),
)
```

And I want to do something like:

```
g.l.Log(
    context.TODO(),
    slog.LevelInfo,
    "Sending request to server.",
    "message", m,
    "Client Connection", client.RemoteAddr().String(),
    "Server Connection", destination.RemoteAddr().String(),
)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: [The package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/log/slog#pkg-overview) offers a few options; the most obvious would seem to be implementing `LogValuer` on your type to return a `Group`, but there's not enough detail on your particular context to offer a specific solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer to this question.

I embedded the slog logger into a custom logger of mine.

```
type Logger struct {
    *slog.Logger
}
```

I also, write export functions for my struct like this:

```
func (m *GatewayMessage) LoggableData() *xlog.RequestData {
    return &xlog.RequestData{
        Request:             m.Request.String(),
        OriginalRequest:     m.OriginalRequest,
    }
}

func (m *GatewayMessage) PopulateGeneralLogData() []any {
    logData := m.LoggableData()
    return []any{
        "Request", logData.Request,
        "OriginalRequest", logData.OriginalRequest,
    }
}
```

Then I write a helper function that gets this GatewayMessage as a parameter and any number of arguments like the Log function of the slog Logger.
This is the debug function for example:

```
func LogDebug(l *xlog.Logger, ctx context.Context, msg string, m *GatewayMessage, args ...any) {
    var generalLogData []any = make([]any, 0)
    if m != nil {
        generalLogData = m.PopulateGeneralLogData()
    }
    args = append(args, generalLogData...)
    l.RuntimeDebug(
        ctx,
        msg,
        args...,
    )
}
```

I'm also using a receiver called `RuntimeDebug` to inject a parameter named Scope in all logs.

```
func (l *Logger) RuntimeDebug(ctx context.Context, msg string, args ...any) {
    args = append(args, "Scope", "Runtime")
    l.Logger.Log(
        ctx,
        slog.LevelDebug,
        msg,
        args...,
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to log the fields and values of the struct, you could also utilize [fmt.Sprintf](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf) with the `%+v` verb to print the struct with it's fields/values. See this go playground for an example: https://go.dev/play/p/NgAcz14_IsL